# App unexpectedly crashes on Launch

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert values into the sqlite database but whenever i added a new insert column command the app crashes.

```
public class EventsDAO implements DAO<Event> {

    private static final String INSERT = "insert into "
            + EventsTable.TABLE_NAME + "(" + EventsColumns._ID + ", "
            + EventsColumns.CHILDNAME +  ", " + EventsColumns.INFO + ", "
            + EventsColumns.PERIOD + ", " + EventsColumns.PERIOD_UNIT + ", "
            + EventsColumns.START_TIME + ") values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";




public long insert(Event event) {
        insertStatement.clearBindings();
        insertStatement.bindNull(1);
        insertStatement.bindString(2, event.getChildname());
        insertStatement.bindString(3, event.getAddress());
        insertStatement.bindLong(4, event.getPeriod().getQuantity());
        insertStatement.bindString(5, event.getPeriod().getUnit());
        insertStatement.bindString(6, Utils.dateToString(event.getStartTime()));

        return insertStatement.executeInsert();
    }
```

i am trying to add new column for contact.The columns are created in database successfully. 
I also tried LOGCAT but i ended with this:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
>                                                                            Process: , PID: 10634
>                                                                            java.lang.InternalError: Thread starting during runtime shutdown
>                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:730)
>                                                                                at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.enableConnectionGC(AbstractConnPool.java:145)
>                                                                                at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.createConnectionPool(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:125)
>                                                                                at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:103)
>                                                                                at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.getHttpClient(HttpRequest.java:214)
>                                                                                at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:141)
>                                                                                at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:225)
>                                                                                at org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:179)
>                                                                                at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:141)
>                                                                                at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)

Comment: Uninstall and Reinstall the app

Comment: i tried that but still getting the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well i solved this problem by following these Method why my app was crashing on launch.

---

> The Databse i'm using is sqlite.

- > Check the created database of app by exporting it to internal storage.

In My Case These were the table columns

```
public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("CREATE TABLE " + EventsTable.TABLE_NAME + " (");
        sb.append(BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ");
        sb.append(EventsColumns.CHILDNAME + " TEXT, ");
        sb.append(EventsColumns.FNAME + " TEXT, " );
        sb.append(EventsColumns.DOB + " TEXT, ");
        sb.append(EventsColumns.GENDER + " TEXT, ");
        sb.append(EventsColumns.ADDRESS + " TEXT, ");
        sb.append(EventsColumns.CONTACT + " TEXT, ");
        sb.append(EventsColumns.INJECTIONNO + " TEXT, ");
        sb.append(EventsColumns.PERIOD + " INTEGER, ");
        sb.append(EventsColumns.PERIOD_UNIT + " TEXT, ");
        sb.append(EventsColumns.START_TIME + " TEXT");
        sb.append(");");
        db.execSQL(sb.toString());
    }
```

> When i exported the created database using this :

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//"+"com.pacakagename"+"//databases//"+databaseName+"";
                String backupDBPath = "backupname.db";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
```

**when i open the sqlite db in Datagrip** i Found out the reason that the column in which i was trying to store my values `<address>`  its *name* was changed due to some space issue.

[The column i was expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuXCp.png)

> AND THE CREATED COLUMN IN DB WAS

[The column name that was created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8iNu.png)

> There was "TEXT" label at the end of the address column
>
> On which inserting values to address the app was crashing and Logcat
>   was unable to explain why This happen.

- The Exception was shown in Logcat when i used `Try()` method on `insert query`

Hope this Post helps.